# Hystrix thread-isolation based on Group Key or Command name?

Tags: semaphore, netflix-zuul, hystrix, netflix

I noticed that Hystrix has two thread-isolation strategy: Thread and Semaphore.

By default Hystrix used Thread strategy and controls it by `hystrix.threadpool.default.coreSize` and because of ca ommand with same group key will use the same thread pool. So it is based on group key.

When Hystrix is using Semaphore strategy, the Semaphore will save in a `ConcurrentHashMap` and the key is command name, will it be based on command name?

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Get the TryableSemaphore this HystrixCommand should use for execution if not running in a separate thread.
 *
 * @return TryableSemaphore
 */
protected TryableSemaphore getExecutionSemaphore() {
  if (properties.executionIsolationStrategy().get() == ExecutionIsolationStrategy.SEMAPHORE) {
    if (executionSemaphoreOverride == null) {
      TryableSemaphore _s = executionSemaphorePerCircuit.get(commandKey.name());
      if (_s == null) {
        // we didn't find one cache so setup
        executionSemaphorePerCircuit.putIfAbsent(commandKey.name(), new TryableSemaphoreActual(properties.executionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests()));
        // assign whatever got set (this or another thread)
        return executionSemaphorePerCircuit.get(commandKey.name());
      } else {
        return _s;
      }
    } else {
      return executionSemaphoreOverride;
    }
  } else {
    // return NoOp implementation since we're not using SEMAPHORE isolation
    return TryableSemaphoreNoOp.DEFAULT;
  }
}
```

Why they have difference scope? I write some testing code to prove it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  int i = 0;
  while (i++ < 20) {
    final int index = i;
    new Thread(() -> {
      System.out.println(new ThreadIsolationCommand(index).execute());
      System.out.println(new SemaphoreIsolationCommand(index).execute());
    }).start();
  }
}

static class ThreadIsolationCommand extends HystrixCommand<String> {

  private int index;

  protected ThreadIsolationCommand(int index) {
    super(
        Setter
            .withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("ThreadIsolationCommandGroup"))
            .andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey(String.valueOf(index)))
            .andCommandPropertiesDefaults(HystrixCommandProperties.Setter()
                .withExecutionIsolationStrategy(HystrixCommandProperties.ExecutionIsolationStrategy.THREAD)
            )
            .andThreadPoolPropertiesDefaults(HystrixThreadPoolProperties.Setter()
                .withCoreSize(10)
            )
    );
    this.index = index;
  }

  @Override
  protected String run() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(500);
    return "Hello Thread " + index;
  }

  @Override
  protected String getFallback() {
    return "Fallback Thread " + index;
  }
}

static class SemaphoreIsolationCommand extends HystrixCommand<String> {

  private int index;

  protected SemaphoreIsolationCommand(int index) {
    super(
        Setter
            .withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("SemaphoreIsolationCommandGroup"))
            .andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey(String.valueOf(index)))
            .andCommandPropertiesDefaults(HystrixCommandProperties.Setter()
                .withExecutionIsolationStrategy(HystrixCommandProperties.ExecutionIsolationStrategy.SEMAPHORE)
                .withExecutionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests(10)
            )
    );
    this.index = index;
  }

  @Override
  protected String run() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(500);
    return "Hello Semaphore " + index;
  }

  @Override
  protected String getFallback() {
    return "Fallback Semaphore " + index;
  }
}
```

This command with same group key and different name, result is :

```
Fallback Thread 9
Fallback Thread 1
Fallback Thread 8
Fallback Thread 19
Fallback Thread 20
Fallback Thread 14
Fallback Thread 3
Fallback Thread 13
Fallback Thread 17
Fallback Thread 10
Hello Thread 5
Hello Semaphore 17
Hello Semaphore 14
Hello Thread 2
Hello Semaphore 3
Hello Thread 7
Hello Thread 15
Hello Thread 4
Hello Semaphore 13
Hello Semaphore 1
Hello Thread 11
Hello Semaphore 20
Hello Semaphore 19
Hello Thread 18
Hello Thread 12
Hello Semaphore 8
Hello Semaphore 9
Hello Thread 6
Hello Thread 16
Hello Semaphore 10
Hello Semaphore 5
Hello Semaphore 2
Hello Semaphore 7
Hello Semaphore 15
Hello Semaphore 4
Hello Semaphore 11
Hello Semaphore 12
Hello Semaphore 6
Hello Semaphore 18
Hello Semaphore 16
```

Only Thread strategy has failed. Is that right?

Comment: any updates on that question? Have you figured it out?